# existence of a differentiable function whose integral is a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $a_n,b_n$ be two sequences such that $a_n$ is increasing and
>   unbounded. Prove that there exists a differentiable function
>   $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for any positive integer $n$ we
>   have $$\int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}f(x)dx=b_n$$

I have no idea how to think about this problem. I can at most assume that since $a_n$ is increasing, we may have $a_{n+1}-a_n=h$ where $h>0$ is a non-zero positive real number ($h\neq 0$ since in this case $a_n$ will be convergent). So we can define a sequence of the form $$s_n=\frac{f(a_{n+1})-f(a_n)}{a_{n+1}-a_n}$$ Afterwards I can't understand if I can use this construction to define such $f$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

For any particular $n$, it's pretty easy to construct an $f_n : \left[a_n, a_{n+1}\right]\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}f_n(x)dx=b_n$, you can just choose any function with a nonzero integral and scale it appropriately. All we need to do is to "stitch together" such functions to a piecewise function. However, we need to take care that it remains differentiable at the boundries, that is:

$$f_n(a_{n+1}) = f_{n+1}(a_{n+1})$$

and

$$f'_n(a_{n+1}) = f'_{n+1}(a_{n+1})$$

A simple way to achieve this is to construct the $f_n$ such that

$$f_n(a_n)=f_n(a_{n+1})=f'_n(a_n)=f'_n(a_{n+1})=0$$

For example

$$f_n(x)=k_n(x-a_n)^2(x-a_{n+1})^2$$

where the scaling factors $k_n$ are chosen so as to ensure that

$$\int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}k_n(x-a_n)^2(x-a_{n+1})^2dx=b_n$$